# The elasticsearch html_strip character filter doesn't work as expected with query_search query

Tags: html, elasticsearch

The behaviour of html_strip character filter looks different with the search query using "**query_string**" and "**match**" query.

1. Created index with "description" field using my_analyzer having html_strip char filter

```
{
  "settings": {
    "analysis": {
      "analyzer": {
        "my_analyzer": {
          "tokenizer": "standard",
          "char_filter": [
            "html_strip"
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "description": {
        "type": "text",
        "analyzer": "my_analyzer"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

2. Indexed as below with sample html content

```
PUT test_index/_doc/001
{
  "description": "<html><body>Hello world</body></html>"
}
```

document created.

3. search using <html> :

```
GET /test_index/_search
{
  "query": {
    "query_string": {
      "query": "<html>"
    }
  }
}
```

Expecting no hits as the html contents would be stripped out internally when using html_strip character filter as per the document (https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-htmlstrip-charfilter.html) but got the result,

result:

```
{
    "took": 2,
    "timed_out": false,
    "_shards": {
        "total": 1,
        "successful": 1,
        "skipped": 0,
        "failed": 0
    },
    "hits": {
        "total": {
            "value": 1,
            "relation": "eq"
        },
        "max_score": 0.2876821,
        "hits": [
            {
                "_index": "test_index",
                "_type": "_doc",
                "_id": "001",
                "_score": 0.2876821,
                "fields": {
                    "description": [
                        "<html><body>Hello world</body></html>"
                    ]
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Returns the record (ideally it should not).

4. Let's search using "match" query:

When **match** query is used it could not find a record when searched using <html> or <body>. whereas it returns record when searched using "Hello" which seems to be the right behaviour of html_strip char filter.

```
GET /test_index/_search
{
    "query": {
    "match": {
      "description": "<html>"
    }
  },
  "fields": [
    "description"
  ],
   "_source": false
}
```

Result:

```
{
    "took": 2,
    "timed_out": false,
    "_shards": {
        "total": 1,
        "successful": 1,
        "skipped": 0,
        "failed": 0
    },
    "hits": {
        "total": {
            "value": 0,
            "relation": "eq"
        },
        "max_score": null,
        "hits": []
    }
}
```

the above query doesn't return any result and looks like the html_strip character filter is working fine with "match" query.

Any suggestions why html_strip character filter is not working as expected with "query_string" query and working with "match" query?

Am I missing anything here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't define any field in your query. By default, it hits **all fields** include `description`, and `description.keyword`.

When you trying with `match` query you are defining the fields :).

### Update query like the following

```
GET /test_html_strip/_search
{
  "query": {
    "query_string": {
      "query": "<html>",
      "fields": ["description"]
    }
  }
}
```